# Why is my callback when the notification permission is granted not being called?

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, android-notifications, android-permissions

I am trying to add notifications to my app. What I am trying to achieve is when the user clicks the "add task" button, they are prompted to enable notifications if the permission has not already been granted. If permission is then granted, my logic to schedule a notification is called. If not, the task is still added and I just don't schedule the notification. If the permission has already been granted, the notification is scheduled.

I find the documentation around this a little confusing but this is the code I have at the moment (NotificationHelper is my class which I will use to schedule/send notifications and I need the taskId and dueDate for the notification):

```
class AddTask : Fragment() {

...
    private val requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
            if (isGranted) {
                scheduleUpcomingDeadlineNotification()
            }
        }
    private var taskId = 0
    private lateinit var dueDate: Date
...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        database = DatabaseHelper(requireContext())
        notifications = NotificationHelper(requireContext())

...
        if (taskName.isNotBlank() && points > 0 && dueDate != null && areSubtasksValid) {
            this.taskId = database.insertTask(taskName, points, dueDate, subtasks)
            this.dueDate = dueDate
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
                != PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
                } else {
                    scheduleUpcomingDeadlineNotification()
                }
            } else {
                scheduleUpcomingDeadlineNotification()
            }
...
        }
...
    }
...
    private fun scheduleUpcomingDeadlineNotification() {
        notifications.scheduleNotificationForUpcomingDeadline(taskId, dueDate)
    }
...
}
```

I do have the permission is the manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />`

and I have set up the notification channel in the Application class.

I have tried following the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#manage-request-code-yourself (both the section to "Allow the system to manage the permission request code" and the section to "Manage the permission request code yourself"). Under both ways of doing it, the callback when the permission is granted by the user is not called, and thus my notification scheduling code is not run. However, it is called when I go back to this fragment and the notification permission has already been granted.

So it is just on the initial granting of the notification permission scenario that the notification is not scheduled.